# Log(3) 243 is not 5

Tags: java, math, logic, program-entry-point

In java, why is the value of log(3)243 not 5 but 4.9999999

```
public class Log{
public static void main(String[] args) {
for(int i=3;i<7652;i=i*3)
System.out.println(i+"    "+Math.log(i)/Math.log(3));
}
}
```

The output for the following code is:

```
27    3.0
81    4.0
243   4.999999999999999
729   6.0
2187  7.0
6561  8.0
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Floating numbers and computer..

Comment: But why does it behave abnormally with  just 243 and not others.??